# Google Play Developer API - quota exceeded

Tags: google-api, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to get a list of reviews for my app. I've been using the Google Play Developer API.

I get the following response after some requests:

```
{ 
   "code" : 403, 
   "errors" : [ { 
     "domain" : "androidpublisher", 
     "message" : "Review query quota exceeded.", 
     "reason" : "reviewQueryQuotaExceeded" 
   } ], 
   "message" : "Review query quota exceeded." 
}
```

I've read about the 200,000 quota - [link](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/quotas). I've also read about the 60 request per hour limit - [link](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews#retrieving_reviews) (bottom of page). I am not sure how one affects the other but I don't think that is the issue.

I don't have other projects and nobody else is using the apis. I haven't edited the quotas on the console.

I've also checked the Google Cloud Platform console and tried to determine my usage. However, there is 0 usage on all APIs judging by the console. I tried to get the usage through the API but I don't think that is possible. Also I don't have billing linked.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing I concluded that the rate at which I can get the list of reviews is roughly 1 request every 2 minutes (0.5 req/min). My code is still running so I cannot comment on a monthly usage yet. I still don't see any data on the console however if it keeps going for a month I will consider this rate to be working.